# Problem on terminal uploading VPN

Tags: package-management, permissions, vpn, openvpn

I am attempting to upload/install open VPN (free) from Source Forge site. Following instructions,copy/paste but receive the following:

```
graeme@graeme-ThinkCentre:~$ apt update && apt -y install ca-certificates wget net-tools
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)

graeme@graeme-ThinkCentre:~$ wget -qO - https://as-repository.openvpn.net/as-repo-public.gpg | apt-key add -
E: This command can only be used by root.

graeme@graeme-ThinkCentre:~$ echo "deb http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian bionic main">/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-as-repo.list
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-as-repo.list: Permission denied

graeme@graeme-ThinkCentre:~$ apt update && apt -y install openvpn-as
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
graeme@graeme-ThinkCentre:~$
```

Comment: @user68186 : just for info as this wont make it in that case of multiples lines, but you know `sudo !!` ?;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `sudo` to run `apt` commands to allow permission.

For example, you should run this instead:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y install ca-certificates wget net-tools
wget -qO - https://as-repository.openvpn.net/as-repo-public.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Additionally, you will encounter a permission issue when you try to use `sudo` with `echo` to write files that need extra permission to write. You can circumvent this by piping `echo` to `sudo tee` instead, like this:

```
echo "deb http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian bionic main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-as-repo.list
```

Comment: I always like to use the `-a` option with `tee` as this will "append" to the last line of a file. Without the `-a` option, you run the risk of overwriting an entire file which can be dangerous so it is good habit to always use `tee -a` unless you *absolutely need* to delete and overwrite an entire file.